# Intent Error at Android Studio (it makes app tiwce)

Tags: android

My Android Studio installs my app twice.

I guess I have some error at  **AndroidManifest.xml**

And I guess I think this error produces from `<intent-filter>`.Because I wrote it twice.

I don't know how to fix the code.

This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".IntroActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are telling Android to mark your two activities as Launchable activity. To solve this issue remove `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` from one of your activity which you do not want to show to user on launcher.

Here's how you should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".IntroActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your easy explanation!! I solve it !! Thanks a lot !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This code is to mark the first activity of the application. Keep this in only first activity you want to open your application with. And remove it from other one.